# In a circular pendulum, where does the equation $v=\sqrt{rg\tan{\alpha}}$ come from?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

In a circular pendulum

[image: circular pendulum]

the $v$ of the particle is $$v=\sqrt{gr\tan{\theta}}$$ where $r$ is the radius and $g$ is the gravity(positive sign), which is equal to $$v=\sqrt{gL\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}}$$But where it comes from?

Comment: You've got a very nice free body diagram there...have you tried applying the rules for uniform circular motion to the appropriate lengths and resultant forces?

Comment: It seems the homework tag applies even if it is not actual homework, cf. the tag description http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it comes from [Euler's Laws of Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_laws_of_motion) applied to a point mass instead of a rigid body (or as they are commonly known as Newton's laws).

Force equals mass times acceleration of the center of gravity. In a pendulum with steady motion, as it is rotating about the $+y$ with speed $\omega$, the tangential speed of the particle is $v=\omega\,r$. The acceleration of the particle, is that of circular motion with radius $r$ or $a = \omega^2 r = v^2/r$.

Since the forces in the vertical direction are balanced then $T\cos\theta = m g$ } $ T = \frac{m g}{\cos\theta}$

In the radial direction we have our equations of motion

$$ T \sin(\theta) = m v^2/r $$
  $$ \frac{m g}{\cos\theta} \sin(\theta) = m v^2/r $$
  $$ g \tan(\theta) =  v^2/r $$
  $$ v = \sqrt{ g\,r\,\tan\theta } $$

Comment: Do NOT give full solutions to [homework] problems. Only hints. See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: @Manishearth There aren't homeworks.

Comment: @Garmen1778: It falls under the [homework] tag, regardless of it being homework. See the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone has forgotten what centripetal force is :)

Whenever you have circular motion, always use CPF as the resultant radial force.

(If you don't know everything behind CPF yet, you ought to learn that first)